# How to Avoid overlap edges in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm developing an application in JSF and I need to show a graph, I'm using cytoscape.js and i embed script in my xhtml page.

I don't know how to avoid overlapping edges, when an entity A has a relationship with another entity B, and entity B has a relationship with entity A the lines overlap. Or when entity A has several lines to the target entity (B).

They seem to be a single line but they should be several towards the same target. Can anybody helpme?

Is there some method or property that can solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide an example of where are you up to with code and what issues you are getting. This helps people understand your problem better. Please spend sometime reading through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I already solved the problem, putting the 'curve-style': 'bezier' property in the edge style section, Thanks.

Comment: That is nice. You are welcome to answer your own question here. I would suggest to modify the question with necessary details and answer your own question. This will help people having the same problem. SO always welcome you to answer your own question.